# Make an element take 100% the width of a page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I tried to change the .navbar width, and only grows to one side. If i add a 100% width, it
will not take the entire page (from the start to the end). Please, help!
CODE (JSX):

```
 return (
    <div className={fix ? `${styles.navbar} ${styles.sticky}` : styles.navbar}>
      <div className={styles["img-wrapper"]}>
        <img className={styles.logo} src={Logo} alt="" />
      </div>
      <ul className={styles["navbar-links"]}>
        <li className={styles["navbar-links__item"]}>
          <a>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li className={styles["navbar-links__item"]}>
          <a>About</a>
        </li>
        <li className={styles["navbar-links__item"]}>
          <a>Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

CODE (CSS):

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 3vh;
  width: 46vw;
  left: 13vw;
  background-color: blue;
}
.img-wrapper {
  display: flex;

  
}

.navbar-links {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}
.navbar-links__item {
  margin-inline: 20px;
}
.navbar-links__item:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: 100vw doesn't work?

Comment: No, does not work

Comment: try setting flex property on the navbar to 
flex: 0 0 100%;

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: Does not work either

Comment: take out the set width you have already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent in React. But if it's CSS, perhaps you have problems with margins. I usually add `margin: 0px;` and `padding: 0px;` on body when I want all the space.

Plus, I would check those 2 lines of .navbar:

```
width: 46vw;
left: 13vw;
```

Perhaps you should change in `width: 100%;` and remove left, or put it to `left: 0px;` instead.